# the output is coming out wrong inspite of the correct logic

Tags: c, reverse

Reverse of a five digit number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, m1, m2, m3, m4;
    clrscr();

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    l1 = a  % 10;
    m1 = a  / 10;
    l2 = m1 % 10;
    m2 = m1 / 10;
    l3 = m2 % 10;
    m3 = m2 / 10;
    l4 = m3 % 10;
    m4 = m3 / 10;
    l5 = m4 / 10;

    printf("\n%d%d%d%d%d", l1, l2, l3, l4, l5);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the logic is correct but output is only coming for the input 12345 and is giving negative numbers for other output.

Comment: Well, if the answers wrong, then the logic is necessarily wrong as well. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Try to use gdb to debug your program and btw conio.h? Which compiler your using?

Comment: Much easier to do if you just read the number as a character string, and print out the characters in reverse order.

Comment: What should happen if the user gives a 4-digit number, or a 6-digit number?  Or are you not at a point where you have to make your programs foolproof?

Comment: "giving negative numbers for other output." --> post that input and the output observed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of problem with the logic here from what I can tell, instead of doing integer division of last digit with 10 do a module or simply print it as is

```
l5=m4/10;
```

change to

```
l5=m4%10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use loops? Try somthing like this maybe:

```
int main ()
{
    int nb;
    int res = 0;
    int if_negative = 1; 

    printf ("%s\n", "Enter number: ");
    scanf ("%d", nb);
    if (nb < 0)                //check if negative
    {
        if_negative = -1;
        nb *= -1;
    }
    while (nb != 0)
    {
        res = res * 10 + (nb % 10);   //build up the answer
        nb /= 10;
    }
    res *= if_negative; 
    ****    // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: No we aren't supposed to use loops

Comment: @Shraddha: if there are artificial constraints on your solution like "can't use loops" or "can't use functions declared in a specific header", you **must** say so in the question.  We can't guess (and shouldn't have to guess) what peculiar constraints are placed on your code by well-meaning teachers.  A loop is a natural way to deal with the problem.

Comment: The loop idea is good.  Note that `nb *= -1;` (what is the minimum value for `nb`?) and `res * 10 + (nb % 10);`  (maybe 1222333999) may overflow.